# Having had nobody stood up for me -correct?

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses

I'm not sure about the following:

> Having advised to many of your colleagues (and yet having had nobody
>   stood up for me when the shit hits the fan), I have decided not to
>   discuss your issues anymore.

or

> Having advised to many of your colleagues (and yet having had nobody
>   stand up for me when the shit hits the fan), I have decided not to
>   discuss your issues anymore.

Comment: You need the infinitive, *stand up*.

Comment: Also, there's something not quite right about your *"Having advised to many of your colleagues"*.

Answer (score 1):

> Having advised many of your colleagues (yet having had **no one stand up for me**  when the shit *hit* the fan), I have decided not to discuss your issues anymore.

The correct rendition of your sentence is above. You'll see that I eliminated some letters and removed a few words (including the *and* which is unnecessary.)

I just want to point out that this is a relatively formal construction, with a very informal *shit hit the fan*. If you cared to, you could bring this in line with the general tone of the rest of your statement:

> Having advised many of your colleagues (yet having had **no one to support me**  when I faced adversity), I have decided not to discuss your issues anymore.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you’ve changed _nobody_ to _no one_? As it happens, I agree _no one_ sounds better in this sentence, but there’s nothing wrong with _nobody_.

Comment: I'm glad that someone else noticed the jarring inconsistency in the formality of the different constructions used here.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be overly combining tenses and I strongly suggest you to construct simpler sentences and avoid using brackets. It is very easy to get lost when a sentence gets too complex and messy.

However, to answer your question:

> having had nobody **stand up** for me when the shit **hit** the fan.

Is correct. After a past tense you need to use the infinitive, however, as the next sentence is related, you need to preserve the tenses and use the past "hit". I would also scrap "the" in front of "shit", but that's just my personal prefference.